# Event Listener in Firestore doesn’t see field updates in documents inside collection. Android, Java

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have next firestore scheme:
collection "users" - document user_id - collection "trips" - document trip_id - collection "requests" - document request_user_id with fields:  and boolean field <is_accepted>

On one of my pages I want to listen to realtime updates of requests: if <is_accepted> changes from 0 to 1(it means user is accepted for a trip).

I have written EventListener to track it:

```
FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            firebaseFirestore
                    .collection("users")
                    .document(user_id)
                    .collection("trip")
                    .document(trip_id)
                    .collection("requests")
                    .whereEqualTo("accepted", 1)
                    .orderBy("timestamp", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
                    .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                            Log.d("Hello", "Triggered");
                            if (error == null) {
                                if (value != null) {///  some actions}}
```

It works fine when to read data first time on the page but when I make updates in document like:

```
HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hashMap.put("timestamp", Timestamp.now());
                hashMap.put("accepted", 1);

                firebaseFirestore
                        .collection("users")
                        .document(user_id)
                        .collection("trips")
                        .document(trip_id)
                        .collection("requests")
                        .document(joined_user_id)
                        .update(hashMap);
```

Listener doesn’t see any changes.
What can be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `joined_user_id` on which you perform the update, had the value of `accepted` equal to `0`? Only that way you can see the chance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your listener is only being added to documents where `accepted` is already set to 1. Remove `.whereEqualTo("accepted", 1)` when registering the listener, or change it to 0 to only listen to documents that have not been accepted yet.

Comment: I am sorry, it is a mistake only in text, I will edit it now

Comment: in the code everything was written correctly, the problem remains the same

Comment: I updated my answer. Your listener is only being added to documents that are already accepted.